# What training is required for a class B endorsement?

Tags: faa-regulations, airspace, class-b-airspace, logbook-endorsements

[14 CFR 61.95](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.95) requires solo student pilots to have an endorsement to (a) fly through class B airspace or (b) takeoff/land at a class B airport.  However, the requirements to get it are pretty vague:

> (1) The student pilot has received both ground and flight training from an authorized instructor on that Class B airspace area, and the flight training was received in the specific Class B airspace area for which solo flight is authorized;

There are similarly vague training requirements for Recreational pilots in [14 CFR 61.101(d)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.101) and Sport pilots in [14 CFR 61.325](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.325).

Is any particular content or amount of time expected, or is it at the CFI's sole discretion to decide when a given pilot is competent enough to endorse? Does the training itself need to be logged as such, separate from the endorsement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not find any guidance other than what you have already noted for Class B airspace endorsements. The ground and flight training requirements seems to be left up to the discretion of the CFI. Though, it seems to be very similar to a solo endorsement as having criteria that is subjective to student and instructor.

Similar to a solo endorsement, a conservative CFI would only endorse the student for a specific airport, in a specific Class B airspace (and not the actual Class B airport), for a specific timeframe, and specific conditions. Even though the endorsement must be given within the preceding 90 days of the flight, the conservative CFI would specify a specific date and time instead of a blanket authority.

That being said, your entire logbook would then serve as a record of adequate training. Previous corresponding flights with the CFI would be logged in the logbook as evidence of training.

Comment: As a side note, I live in an area with a very busy Class B. There are a lot of airports under the overlying Class B shelf. Each of those airports has a myriad of flight schools and independent CFIs. Those CFIs take their students into and through the Class B on a regular basis. Some even land at the Class B airport in the middle of the night when the tower is not as busy. So far, I have not personally heard of anyone giving or receiving a Class B endorsement for this area. As small of a sample size as my personal experience is.

Comment: Same with the B at my school, but my CFI had no problem giving it when I asked.  My night endorsement was another story!